# I can't copy files from a HDD, do I need permission from my own account?

Tags: permissions, backup, windows-8

My friend wanted me to backup all the photos and music and text documents on his hard drive so I'm trying to do that. He gave me the whole computer. It's an OEM machine from 2005 running Windows XP.

My computer recognizes the drive but anytime I try to copy or even open a file, it says I need read permissions from my own account. "You need permission from BranPC in order to view this file".

So I gave myself full read permissions but it's still telling me access denied and I still need read permissions.

I googled it and it said go on the hidden administrator account to do it, so I did but I still get the error.

Another link said download this program and it will show you the processes that keep the drive locked and the only processes that are keeping it locked according to that program are explorer.exe and ntoskrnl.exe (says 'System' on the program).

How do I backup these pictures? Is there some kind of program I can use to do it on Windows 8? If I keep the HDD plugged in and then boot into a Linux live CD on my machine, will it work for me?

If you're wondering why I don't just use my friend's PC that has all permissions, it's because it's Windows XP with 1GB of RAM and it's totally crapped, so it takes an hour just for it to notice I plugged an SD card into the card reader.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use PStool from sysinternals. One of small command line programs in that package allow you to open any program as System account so you can do whatever you want. In this case you start cmd.exe as System using PSexec.exe and then you can do what you desire

Answer (score 0):

Depending on files i would imagine you need permissions by the owner of the file. It can also depend on the file properties if the owner allows other people access to the files.

Comment: file system and permissions were made on another system, though.

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions?

Comment: I'm not the OP ...

Comment: Sorry I might as well be totally blind, and im sure its still possible to check who can modify files...